# RealTimeEventSettings error when pulling source

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

I am unable to resolve an error related to [RealTimeEventSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_realtimeeventsettings.htm) when pulling the source from a scratch org. I believe this settings file is a result of toggling [real-time event monitoring settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.event_monitoring_monitor_events_with_event_manager.htm&type=5) - which I have since set back to default, however, this settings file has persisted.

> ERROR running force:source:pull:  Settings type:
> 'RealTimeEventSettings' is unknown

I am using:

- sfdx version: sfdx-cli/7.110.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.3
- cli apiVersion: 52.0

Update: The problem resolved itself but I cannot identify why.

Comment: I didn't try it, but I would have following ideas in mind:

- if the file exists locally, delete it
- Delete Record containing the reference  from SourceMember data table
- set the RealTimeEventSettings into the .forceignore

I didn't grasp the problem with all the necessary information, but maybe one of these points fits your problem^^

Comment: The file did not exist locally. I am curious though about how I query these records. Do you have a good reference for a beginner @Hyperzwerg ?

Comment: sorry for ignoring your comment for such a long time! You can query this by using the developer console, mind ticking "Use Tooling API" thought. Here is the api reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm | Otherwise I can recommend reading through some parts of the salesforce cli. | sfdx force:data --help | would be the entry point for commands helping you analyse things with your local environment